# To express a integrable function as difference.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Assume $f$ is an integrable function on $[0,1]$. I want to find functions $g$ and $h$, so that $f=g-h$ almost everywhere. The functions $g$ and $h$ should be pointwise limits of continuous functions $g_n$ and $h_n$, and both two sequences $g_n(x)$, $ h_n(x)$ are required to be increasing when $x$ is fixed.

Any help would be grateful, thanks.

Comment: @TooOldForMath $g_n$ should be continuous...

Comment: @TooOldForMath I don't see why every integrable function should be Baire class 1. Example 1 in the first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614429/examples-of-baire-class-2-functions) is Riemann integrable but not of Baire class 1.

Comment: Sorry overread :D.

Answer (score 1):

If such $g_n$, $h_n$ exist, then $f$ is the pointwise limit of the sequence $g_n-h_n$. Therefore, $f$ belongs to [Baire class 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function#Classification_of_Baire_functions). [David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680717/to-express-a-integrable-function-as-difference#comment1429044_680717) gave a [link to an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614429/examples-of-baire-class-2-functions) of a Riemann integrable function that is not of Baire class 1.

Therefore, such $g_n$ and $h_n$ cannot be found in general.

Comment: Oh, sorry for my mistake. I just want f=g-h almost everywhere. Will the proposition be correct this time?