# Is a function with a dense set of points of continuity of Baire Class 1?

Tags: continuity, baire-category

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be an arbitrary  function. It is well known that if $f$ is of Baire Class 1, then the points at which $f$ is continuous form a dense subset of $[0,1]$. My question now is, if the converse is true:

> Let $f$ be continuous at each point of a dense subset of $[0,1]$. Is then $f$ necessarily of Baire Class 1?

I guess not, and I would like to see some references showing a counter example or, even better, some book/paper answering this and the following question:

> If the answer to the above question is negative, what additional property on $f$ is needed to guarantee that $f$ is of Baire Class 1?

I suppose that the set of continuity in a certain sense has to be bigger than just dense.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's automatically somewhat "bigger"; the set of continuity is always $G_\delta$, so if it is dense then it is comeager and in particular (by Baire category) not meager.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564333/maximum-baire-class-of-a-riemann-integrable-function). It's just a stronger result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the first example at [Examples of Baire class 2 functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614429/examples-of-baire-class-2-functions/614435#614435); you put a continuous "sawtooth" of height 1 in each of the intervals in the complement of the Cantor set $C$.  Then it is continuous at every point of $C^c$ and discontinuous at every point of $C$. However, a Baire class 1 function restricted to any perfect set has a comeager continuity set, so this function is not Baire class 1.  (It is Baire class 2.)

Also see [Maximum Baire class of a Riemann integrable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564333/maximum-baire-class-of-a-riemann-integrable-function/1564502#1564502) for a function which is continuous at each point of a dense set, but is not even Borel: just consider $1_B$ where $B$ is any non-Borel subset of the Cantor set.  (Thanks to  MathematicsStudent1122 for suggesting this in a comment.)

For a result in the other direction, it seems to be true that if the continuity set is *co-countable* (i.e. the discontinuity set is countable) then the function is Baire class 1.  This appears as Exercise 24.17 in Kechris, *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, but I can't solve it off the top of my head.  None of the other notions of "big set" seem to help; the examples above show that it is not sufficient for the continuity set to be comeager or full measure (or both).