# If $f$ is differentiable on [a,b], must there be a subinterval on which$f’(x)$ be bounded?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

If $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, then there must be $(\alpha,\beta)\subset [a,b]$, such that $f’(x)$ is bounded on $(\alpha,\beta)$. To prove it or to give an counter-example.

The question may have something to do with the intermediate value theorem.

I understand if there is no such $(\alpha,\beta)$, then for every $x\in[a,b]$, there exists ${x_n}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n=x$, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |f’(x_n)|=+\infty$. But I still cannot work things out.

Comment: [This](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/teaching/m447f16/BaireCategory.pdf) may be of interest to you (page 4)

Answer (score 4):

$f'(x)=\lim \frac {f(x+\frac  1n) -f(x)} {1/n}$. It is a known consequence of Baire Category Theorem that pointwise limits of continuous functions have lots of points of continuity: They are continuous on a dense set of points. If $f'$ is continuous at $c$ then it is bounded in some interval around $c$.

Answer (score 3):

### Every derivative is bounded on a dense set of intervals.

*(StackExchange says to be nice to a new contributor. Hence the elaboration on the other [correct] posted answer.)*

The current answer is what any trained mathematician will respond.  If you wake us at 3:00am after a night of drinking we may not remeber much about the evening but if you ask this question we will mutter immediately (exactly as did the other poster):

(i)  Every derivative belongs to the first class of Baire. (See ref [1].)

(ii) Every function in the first class of Baire is continuous at the points of a residual set.  (See ref [2].)

(iii) If a function is continuous at a point it is necessarily bounded in a neighborhood of that point. (See any calculus text.)

From those three observations  the answer is clear: a derivative must be bounded on each of a dense set of subintervals.  The only "deep" step is (ii) and that is proved using the Baire category theorem.

---

**ALTERNATIVELY:** The OP suggested that, maybe, some more elementary property of derivatives and continuous functions might answer this, e.g., the mean-value theorem perhaps?

My guess is that you need the Baire category theorem to get something like this, although an elementary method is worth a try.  Arguably, though, the Baire category theorem is not that deep and should be a ready tool for a student anyway.

In the text [3] see **Section 6.4 The Baire Category Theorem** for an account of this theorem which is not particularly demanding or advanced.  Many students may encounter this theorem only in a study of complete metric spaces.

**CONSIDER THIS METHOD:**

If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and has a finite derivative at each point of a set $D$ then, for each $n=1,2,3,\dots$, let  $E_n$ be the set of points $x$ with the property that
$$ y\in [a,b],\ 0<|x-y|\leq \frac1n \implies \left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right|\leq n.$$

Check (using continuity) that each $E_n$ is closed and that every point in $D$ belongs to at least one of the sets in the sequence $\{E_n\}$.

Now bring out the heavy guns:  if $D=[a,b]$ the sequence of closed sets $\{E_n\}$ covers that interval so, by the Baire category theorem one of the sets must contain an interval  $(c,d)$.  On that interval $f'$ is evidently bounded.

Note: the other method is not about derivatives, really only about pointwise limits of continuous functions.  This technique is useful for a detailed analysis of derivatives in more general situations.

---

**REFERENCES:**

[1] [About references for Baire class one function and Baire class two function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4171420/about-references-for-baire-class-one-function-and-baire-class-two-function)

[2] https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32033/points-of-continuity-of-baire-class-one-functions

[3] *Elementary Real Analysis* text (free PDF):
https://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf