# Every circle passes through points of all colors

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Is it possible to color every point in the plane in one of $n$ colors so that every (nondegenerate) circle contains points of every color?

If we can do the coloring so that every arbitrarily small interval of $x$-coordinate contains all the colors, we would be done, since a circle must contain all points of some interval of $x$-coordinate. This reduces the problem to $1$ dimension. But how can we do this coloring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second paragraph proves that we can do this with continuum many colors.  The two answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614345/examples-of-nowhere-continuous-functions/614443#614443) and the ones [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790927/is-there-a-function-f-colon-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-such-that-every-non-empty-o/1060374#1060374) describe functions that take all real values in any interval of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_i$ be the $i$th prime; and define $A_i = \{r \in \mathbb Q : \exists a,b \in \mathbb Z $ with $gcd(a,p_i)=1$, $b>0$, and $ r = \frac{a}{(p_i)^b}\}$. Each $A_i$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and they are mutually disjoint; so color each point $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ as color $i$ if $y \in A_i$ (and color 1 if $y$ is not in any $A_i$).