# Can we always use the language of set theory to talk about functions?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

A relation is a set, and a function is a specific kind of relation. Therefore a function is a set also.

However, at the levels of math I've studied (undergraduate only), I get the feeling people don't talk about functions as sets in the purest sense.

With the aim of better understanding whether there's some sort of informal line between functions and sets, **here's one question I have:**

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. (With domain all real numbers greater than or equal to 0)

Let $g(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$. (With domain all real numbers)

**Is it correct to say $f \subseteq g$ ? How about $f(x) \subseteq g(x)$?**

**More broadly, am I right to notice a line between functions and sets? Can we always use the language of set theory to talk about functions?**

Comment: Yes, in this case $f \subseteq g$.

Comment: One way to think about a function $$f: A \mapsto B$$ is to think about it as an element of the set of functions that map from the set A to the set B

Comment: @BolutifeOgunsola: The notation is $f:A\rightarrow B$. Your symbol links the function argument with its value, e.g. $x\mapsto \sqrt x$.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90820/set-theories-without-junk-theorems

Comment: You can, but that doesn't mean you should. For example, it's also true in standard set theory that $2 \subset 3$, but this is more of a coincidence (or implementation detail, to make an analogy with programming) than a mathematical truth.

Comment: Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=e^x$, and consider the map $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ given by $g(x)=e^x$. Then $g$ is a bijection, while $f$ is not. If we formalize a function as the set of ordered pairs, we have the problem that $f$ and $g$ become the same set! You cannot reconstruct the codomain from the graph set, yet in our daily lives we consider the codomain a property of a function. This suggests we should formalize a function $f:A\to B$ as a triple $(A,B,\Gamma )$ where $\Gamma$ is the graph (set of ordered pairs).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you think about a function as a set, it is a set of ordered pairs.  The first element of the pair belongs to the domain, the second to the range.  When you refer to the function as a whole, it should be $f$ or $g$, not $f(x)$ which should be the value of the function at $x$.  Seen as a set of ordered pairs, every pair that belongs to $f$ also belongs to $g$, so you can say $f \subset g$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially for the difference between f and f(x). One question: You say "Seen as a set of ordered pairs..." That makes it sound like functions can't always be thought of that way. Is there ever a situation where it's off-limits to think of a function as a set of ordered pairs?

Comment: @user404789: It's never off limits, and always valid. But there are situations where it's not useful. For instance, if you are planning a car journey, you don't need to consider how many revolutions the wheels will make.

Comment: Some people define a function to include information about the domain and range.  Your $f$ would be a function from the non-negative reals to the reals (or to the non-negative reals) while $g$ is from all the reals to the same place.  It then becomes problematic to say $f \subset g$ because the function becomes a bunch of ordered pairs plus a wrapper and we don't know what to make of the subset language as it applies to the wrapper.

Comment: But the only purpose my wrapper serves is to specify which ordered pairs the function includes. If the function is just a set at its heart, then the wrapper simply helps to pick the pairs in the set, after which we can forget about it. What we're left with is a set with no extra baggage. Right?

Comment: That would be right.  And if you get rid of the baggage your subset thing works fine.  I have seen people get very picky about the wrappers, though.  I think the mainstream view would support yours.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user404789: This answer applies if ZFC set theory is the chosen foundation (it is the mainstream one). It does not apply in general. Also, even for ZFC, the powerset-operation is **not** a function and cannot be one without producing a contradiction. So be careful in assuming that everything we can **conceive** of as a function-like object is actually a set. If you look at the axiom of replacement, it is precisely there to reify all function-like objects whose domain is a set, and of course it does not apply to $\mathcal{P}$.

Comment: @RossMillikan - I have a quick question pertaining to your post and the OP's question: When we say things like "the map $f$ sends/maps/associates every $x \in X$ to exactly one $y \in Y$",  "the map $f$ assigns to every $x \in X$ exactly one $y \in Y$" or in geometry we may discuss how a map transforms or how it pushes forward
or pulls back more complicated objects than point, *etc.*, - are these all equivalent ways of thinking about maps (different ways of thinking about the same thing)?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: the maps you are referring to in geometry are a small subset of the functions.  They are at least continuous and probably continuously differentiable.  The whole set of functions from a plane to a plane is much more general.  For functions in general there is no reason to suspect that nearby points are sent anywhere nearby each other.  It then doesn't make much sense to talk of where a function sends a square because bits of it are sent all over the plane.  Within the group of functions  you are talking about, it is the same thing.

Comment: @RossMilikan - Gotcha! However, I think my question may have come out wrong. I was more asking if it’s correct to say that those statements I mentioned are just different ways of *thinking* about functions? My reason for asking was just to be able to explain this to someone if they were to ask about this. Thank you for your previous answer as well :-).

Comment: @TaylorRendon:   I think they are a very different way of thinking about functions, not just a different way.  It goes back to early algebra classes where we go to the board and "draw a function".  These functions are always nice and smooth, which gives many people the impression that functions must be so.  Later we learn about functions as expressions and many people think every function must have a simple expression.  We see lots of complaints here about using even case statements in functions.

Comment: @TaylorRendon:    I give an example of a function whose graph is dense in the unit square in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614345/examples-of-nowhere-continuous-functions/614443#614443

Answer (score 14):

There are two separate things:

1) How we think about mathematical objects; and

2) How we *formalize* mathematical objects within set theory.

People such as Archimedes, Eudoxus, Newton, Euler, and Gauss did brilliant math long before the development of set theory. Clearly set-theoretic formalization is not a prerequisite of doing math.

The formalization of mathematical objects in the context of set theory is a relatively recent historical development, having taken place between say the late nineteenth century and much of the twentieth. During that period of time mathematicians found a need for more rigorous foundations, and set theory turned out to be highly useful for this purpose. It's not necessarily the last word on foundations; nor do we spend much time caring about the formalization most of the time.

For example if we are in calculus class and we encounter the function defined by $f(x) = x^2$, we typically think of it as a machine or black box that inputs a real number and outputs the square of the input. Nobody thinks of it as a set of ordered pairs.

On the other hand if we're learning analytic geometry for the first time, given $f(x) = x^2$ we make a table containing a few sample pairs $(x, x^2)$, then we plot those points in the $x$-$y$ plane, and we see that the dots seem to form a parabola. When we graph a function we are implicitly using the idea of a function as a set of ordered pairs!

The best way to think about this is that we have two points of view, the intuition and the formalism. We go back and forth between them as needed. Sometimes a function is a machine or a mapping or a correspondence, and sometimes it's a set of ordered pairs. Whichever point of view helps us at any given moment.

One can ask about the nature of the relationship between the intuitive idea of a function (or any other mathematical object) and the set-theoretic symbology that represents or models that object. This is a question of philosophy.

Perhaps functions and numbers and sets exist in some abstract Platonic realm, and our symbols are accurate representations of them. Or perhaps our symbols are helpful but inaccurate representations. Or perhaps there are no functions or numbers or sets at all, just strings of symbols manipulated in accordance with formal rules. In that latter point of view, math is just a game like chess. Nobody thinks the laws of the universe are written in chess, but many people think the laws of the universe are written in math. Why are the rules of math so different than the rules of chess?

Many smart people have thought deeply about these issues. But when they think about these things they are doing philosophy, not math.

The takeaway is that when we do math, we use both intuition and formalism, whichever is most helpful at any given moment. And we don't think about the philosophy, unless we are doing philosophy.

Comment: I don't know enough about set theory to vote on this answer, but this was an incredibly enjoyable and fascinating read!

Comment: @DrewBuckley Thanks much.